# TypeError: serve() got an unexpected keyword argument 'document_root'

Tags: python, html, django, typeerror

my problem Here the image/file that the user uploaded aren't being displayed(They are being saved though!!) when I run the site using Terminal I get an error message on Terminal `TypeError: serve() got an unexpected keyword argument 'document_root'` but the site runs just fine. when I open my site on chrome it displays name of the image/file and only a symbol of an image/file but i want it to display the image/file it self not a symbol.

**Setting.py:**

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

( This only some part of the urls.py)

**urls.py**:

```
from django.urls import path
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, documnet_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

( This is also some part of the html file that displays the image)

**file.html**

```
{% if model.image %}
    <image src="{{model.image.url}}">
{% endif %}
```

Comment: May be a typo. In the code,  I see `documnet_root` which is spelled wrong.

Comment: That's the case Tank you very much!! I was too tired to realize the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(moving comment to answer)

Just a typo:

`documnet_root` should be `document_root`

Comment: This is a bit old but please don't answer typo questions. Close it as "Not reproducible or was caused by a typo"

Answer (score -3):

mine was upper uppercase for argument **document**

urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, **Document_root**=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)

this fixed my problem

urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, **document_root**=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).